# Fire method when a specific nsdate has passed

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nstimer

I want my App to call a method at an setter NSDate (It only needs to happen when the app is active, I'll handle passed events on launch in the app delegate).

I read about some ways to achieve such a behavior: On the one hand to work with `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` (But this doesn't look like a good way for me) or on the other hand to work with an `NSTimer`.

What is the best way regarding the app performance? One requirement is that you can cancel the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `NSTimer` is a simple solution. It has a property called `fireDate` that tells you when it's going to fire next. And it's a writeable property, so you can set that date to whatever you want.

Cancel the event by invalidating the timer object.